# Pass currnet ngFor item into compontent @Input()

Tags: angular

I want to loop over some data and use my component to display it like this:

```
<my-component *ngFor="currentItem of items" [item]="currentItem>
</my-component>
```

Is there a way to pass this without using a parent component for the ngFor?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
<my-component *ngFor="let currentItem of items">{{ currentItem  }} </my-component>
```